# Solving differential system with repeated eigenvalue

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve $$ \frac{dx}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &-2  & 0\\ 
2 & 5 & 0\\ 
2 &1  &3 
\end{bmatrix}x$$
and find that it has only one eigenvalue $3$ of multiplicity $3$. Also, $ \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}$ is an eigenvector to $3$ and so, $ \begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}e^{3t}$ is a solution to the system. Now in my book, if an eigenvalue is repeated twice, then it says how to achieve another solution. But, this eigenvalue is repeated thrice and I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Do you know something about diagonalization and the Jordan normal form of a matrix?

Comment: Yes, I know of both

Answer (score 1):

$$x'=Ax$$
You have a first eigenvector $v_1=\pmatrix {0,0,1}^t$ and a solution $x_1=v_1e^{3t}$
.Then for a second vector you have to calculate $v_2$:
$$(A-3I)v_2=v_1$$
$$\pmatrix {-2 & -2 &0 \\ 2&2&0 \\ 2&1&0} \pmatrix {v_{21} \\v_{22} \\v_{23}}=\pmatrix {0 \\0\\1}$$
You can take $v_2=\pmatrix {1 ,-1,0}^t$. Then a second solution is:
$$x_2=(v_2+tv_1)e^{3t}$$
For the third eigenvector solve for $v_3$:
$$(A-3I)v_3=v_2$$
Then the solution is:
$$x_3=e^{3t} \left(\dfrac {t^2}2v_1+tv_2+v_3\right)$$
And the complete solution is:
$$x(t)=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+c_3x_3$$

Comment: What about the third solution? It's a $3\times 3$ matrix.

Comment: @Achak0790 I adde some lines. I hope it's clear.

Comment: Many many thanks. I need to know the procedure for $v_3$.

Comment: For ? You need to learn about generalized eigenvectors @Achak0790

Comment: It's the same as the procedure for $v_2$ @Achak0790

Comment: Yeah, I get the idea now, thanks